# Plotting the intersection of several 3D half-spaces?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, scipy

I have a number of (between 5 and 50) 3D linear inequalities (for instance, `2x + 3y - z >= 2`), each of which define a half-space in 3D.

I need to plot the polyhedron formed by the intersection of these half-spaces (which is going to have infinite volume), in a particular 3D region. It is sufficient to just plot the boundary surface of the polyhedron.

Could this library be useful? [`scipy.spatial.HalfspaceIntersection`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.HalfspaceIntersection.html). The example uses 2D plots and `matplotlib`, interested in a 3D `matplotlib` plot.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method is by using `mayavi.mlab.contour3d()`:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-50:50:100j, -50:50:100j, -50:50:100j]

V = ((2 * X + 3 * Y - Z >= 2) & 
     (4 * X - 2 * Y + Z <= 10) &
     (X + Y + Z >= 1)).astype(float)

mlab.contour3d(X, Y, Z, V, contours=[0.5])
```

the output:

[image]